# Trimming Magento's Grid Submissions

Tags: grid, ajax

I find that the users of our Magento backend/back office waste a lot of time having to resubmit data just because of trailing spaces when trying to filter Magento grids.

Consider the following example:

[image]

You'll see that there is a trailing space after "test", namely "test ".
If the user presses enter, no results are returned because there's no match.

I'd like Magento to automatically trim this submission so that it get's rid of preceding & trailing spaces.

**Update**: Thanks to *oleksii.svarychevskyi*'s answer:

I applied a local override:

`app/code/core/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php`, the method now reads as follows:

```
protected function _setFilterValues($data)
{
    foreach ($this->getColumns() as $columnId => $column) {
        if (isset($data[$columnId])
            && (!empty($data[$columnId]) || strlen($data[$columnId]) > 0)
            && $column->getFilter()
        ) {
            if (is_array($data[$columnId])){
                $new_values = array();
                foreach ($data[$columnId] as $key => $value){
                    $new_values[$key] = trim($value);
                }
                $column->getFilter()->setValue($new_values);
            }
            else{
                $column->getFilter()->setValue(trim($data[$columnId]));
            }
            $this->_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

The `is_array()` section handles data submission where the filter consists of up to two values (i.e Date, qty, price etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rewrite method `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_setFilterValues()`

```
    foreach ($this->getColumns() as $columnId => $column) {
        if (isset($data[$columnId])
            && (!empty($data[$columnId]) || strlen($data[$columnId]) > 0)
            && $column->getFilter()
        ) {
            $column->getFilter()->setValue($data[$columnId]);
            $this->_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
    }
    return $this;
```

This method is responsible for setting filter values to filter.

Or you can rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Filter_Abstract::getCondition()`

Which is responsible for creating condition.

In one of these methods you can **trim** values.